# fql.multiquery doesn't work as expected

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

```
$pairs = $facebook->api(array(
        'method' => 'fql.multiquery',
        'queries' => array(
            'query1' => 'SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me()',
            'query2' => 'SELECT uid1, uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 IN (#query1) AND uid2 IN (#query1)'
        )
));
```

That gives me a `Parser error: unexpected '#query1' at position 45.` error, which I don't understand. I thought the above was exactly how it was supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to build query2 is

`SELECT uid1, uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 IN (SELECT uid1 FROM #query1) AND uid2 IN (SELECT uid1 FROM #query1)`

But overall this call is inefficient. The request will fail because it's too resource intensive. You're probably going to have the break up the second call per friend.